# How to sort hash by numerical values in Ruby without converting to array?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash: `{"spider" => 213, "frog" => 128, "apple" => 812}`.

How can I reorder that so that it orders them by the value in descending order without converting it to an array? So, changing that to `{"apple" => 812, "spider" => 213, "frog" => 128}` without making it into an array.

I've tried `.sort_by`, but that converts it to an array.

Comment: You can't. Hashes don't retain sort order.

Comment: They do. Hashes in Ruby are now ordered structures, as of 1.9.3.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky But only insertion order of keys.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby 1.9, "[Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)", so just make sure you insert them in the right way:

```
Hash[h.sort_by { |_, v| -v }]
#=> > {"apple"=>812, "spider"=>213, "frog"=>128}
```

Comment: Oh, so what Matz said before is not true anymore? Do we nw have sort method on hashes?

Comment: `sort_by` comes from `Enumerable` and `Hash`es do include that mixin. This basically does hash -> array -> hash, making sure the keys get inserted in the right order.

Comment: You are right, there is one! Up to the point that it returns an array of pairs, which is what the asker wanted not ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to sort the hash itself, or just operate on its contents in sort order?  If the latter, then this snippet would work:

```
myhash.keys.sort.each { |k| .... do something with myhash[k] .... }
```

The only approach I can see, apart from simply populating the hash in sorted order to start with, is to use an intermediate array:

```
Hash[myhash.sort]
```

But you, as the programmer, don't 'see' the intermediate state.  Using the sort method on a hash converts the hash to a sorted array of arrays, and the #[] method coerces the array into a hash.  On Ruby-1.9.3, at least.

Comment: The only approach is to delete the keys from the array and append them to it using #merge. But the requirement not to use Arrays is weak from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

So the question is not irrelevant. But, why? What do you mean by reorder? In place reorder? No matter what you do, you will have to somehow extract the values from the hash. Why are you afraid of arrays? Do you know that small hashes are now implemented as arrays in Ruby? (Or will be in 2.0?) Matz refrained from adding sort method to hashes on purpose, I read his post on this topic...

Comment: How exactly would you implement a hash with non-numeric keys as an array? Do you have any reference on that part? I could imagine the other way round, like Lua does...

Comment: Well, I dunno how, but I'm not making it up - I read it honest.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the original Matz comments about that.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to find it. He said: "Hash is now ordered ... I am hesitating to add #sort method on it", or something very very similar.